# Accuring reference to public key status in braintree IOS

Tags: ios, payment-gateway, payment, braintree

I'm developing an iOS Project using a `Braintree Payment roll` for transaction processing. I'm using the API at [SCViewController.m line 86 from the Braintree iOS Library](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/master/braintree/SampleCheckout/SCViewController.m#L86) and that code was working perfectly.

I created a new Braintree Sandbox accout and put its encryption key into our project, but now I get this error:

> Problem acquiring reference to the public key, OSStatus == 0

What do I need to do to make the new encryption key work in my project?

Answer (score 2):

The `SampleProject` is creating a `VTClient` object [here](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/master/braintree/SampleCheckout/SCAppDelegate.m#L61). When that object is created, you pass in your Braintree client-side encryption key and your merchant ID.

That error is happening because you're passing in an incorrect Braintree client-side encryption key. Please make sure that you're using the correct sandbox client-side encryption key and sandbox merchant ID, which can be found logging in to the [sandbox Braintree site](https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/login).

Also, keep in mind that there are different client-side encryption keys and merchant IDs for sandbox vs production environments. When you create the `VTClient`, you can specify which environment you're working in - and ensure that you're passing in the appropriate credentials for that environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @johngraham i followed all the procedures as mentioned in documentation and used Correct encrypt keys given for my Brain tree account.but still i get the same error.

Comment: Hmm. A few questions: where did you get your sandbox Braintree client-side encryption key and merchant ID from? Also, are you initializing `VTClient` with the sandbox environment? And lastly, can you confirm that when the `VTClient` is initialized, you're passing in those correct keys?

Comment: sorry for the delay @johngraham I got the Encryption key and Merchant Id from this link "sandbox.braintreegateway.com";. I initialized key in VenmoTouchFramework and VenmoTouchSettings.h and using in appdelegate class. - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{ [self initVTClient]; } - (void) initVTClient { if ([BT_ENVIRONMENT isEqualToString:@"sandbox"]) { [VTClient startWithMerchantID:BT_SANDBOX_MERCHANT_ID braintreeClientSideEncryptionKey:BT_SANDBOX_CLIENT_SIDE_ENCRYPTION_KEY environment:VTEnvironmentSandbox];

Answer (score 0):

Braintree dev here - as a result of some recent internal upgrades, a small number of CSE keys in our sandbox were generated incorrectly. From your error message, it looks like you may have been bit by this issue.

We've regenerated keys for the affected users.  If you go back to the Sandbox and copy your new CSE key, it should now work. If it doesn't, please reach out to our support (support@braintreepayments.com) directly and we'll be in touch.

Thanks,

-SP